When is $1+2(p-3)!$ a power of $p?$

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Show that $1+2(p-3)!$ is not a power of $p$ for $p>7.$

For $p\in\{3,5,7\},$ the above expression is indeed a power of $p.$
From Wilson's Theorem,
$$2(p-1)!\equiv_p-2$$
$$\implies 2(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)!\equiv_p-2$$
$$\implies 2(p-3)!\equiv_p-2×(2^{-1})$$
$$\implies 1+2(p-3)!\equiv_p0$$
So, the above expression is divisible by $p.$ Hence, if we show that it is not divisible by $p^2,$ we will be done (if it is even true that it is not divisible by $p^2$). I don't know how to proceed further.
Edit: This was on a past number theory exam given at my university.

This could be very hard. "Wilson primes" are primes $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $(p-1)!+1$, and all that's known about them is that there are at least three ($5$, $13$, and $563$), and if there are any more they must be at least $2\times10^{13}$.

So, it's quite possible that nobody knows how to proceed further. It's also quite possible that nobody cares.

Hint:  Let $p = 2q+1$, $1+2(p-3)! = p^k$, split into cases where $q$ is prime. Conclude that $ k \geq p$ hence there are no solutions.

@GerryMyerson, well I care since this was a question on a past number theory exam given in my university. I expected this to be able to be solved in an exam setting.

It would have been good to include that information in your original post, aqua.

@GerryMyerson, edited it in.

Let $p^k -1 =2(p-3)!$ and $ p = 2q+1$.
Since $p > 7$, so $ p \geq 11, q \geq 5$.
Case 1: If $q\geq 5$ is composite.
Show that $(p-1)^2 \mid 2(p-3)!$
Dividing throughout by $p-1$,
$$ p^{k-1} + p^{k-2} + \ldots + 1 = \frac{2(p-3)! } { p-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}.$$
Hence $k  \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}$. Since $ k > 0$, thus $k \geq p-1$.
Observe that naively, $p^k = 1+ 2(p-3)! < (p-2)! < p^{p-2}$, so $ k < p-2$. This is a contradiction.
Case 2: If $ q\geq 5$ is prime (Thanks Sophie Germain) .
We only have $(p-1) \mid \mid 2(p-3)!$, so the above trick won't work. But let's still give it a try and see what information we can extract.
Dividing throughout by $p-1 = 2q$,
$$ p^{k-1} + p^{k-2} + \ldots + 1 = (q-1)! \times (q+1)(q+2)\ldots (2q-2) \equiv (-1) \times 1 \pmod{q}$$
Let's eliminate possibilities of $ k \equiv -1 \pmod{q}$.  Show that

$p^k = 1 + 2(p-3)! < p^{p-2}$ so $ k < p-2 = 2q-1$  as before, leaving the pesky case of
$p^k = 1+ 2(p-3)! > (p-3)! > p^{(p-3)/2 } $ for $ p > 10$  so $ k > \frac{p-3}{2} =   q-1$.

Hence there are no solutions.
Notes

We never used the fact that $p$ is prime. It is not needed other than to avoid the small cases.
The motivation for this comes from modifying the proof that $n^k = (n-1)! + 1 $ has no solutions for $n > 5$. This holds for all natural numbers, not just primes, as does the above.
It's late, so I might have made some calculation errors. If so, let me know. Thanks Aleksei Kulikov.


"We know that $(p-3)! < p^{\frac{p-3}{2}}$" -- umm, this is just false, the proof you had in mind (with pairing) actually straight up proves the opposite inequality. This can be saved, though, by saying that $k \equiv -1 (\text{mod } q)$, so if $k \neq q-1$, then $k \ge 2q-1 = p - 2$, and now $1 + 2(p-3)! < p^{p-2}$ actually holds.

@AlekseiKulikov Thanks! This should be fixed now.
